# AJAX PHP not returning a value

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am not sure what I am missing. Is there anything wrong with my syntax on the below? I am trying to request an answer using an HTML form and then check the answer against a value with a PHP script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Verify Identity</title>
    </head>
<script>
        function verify(e) {
            if((e && e.keyCode == 13) || e == 0) {
                document.forms.verifyForm.submit();
                var golfer = document.getElementById("mgolf").value;
                // window.alert("You answered: " + golfer);
                //adding the ajax php call attempt 1 
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("servRes").innterHTML = this.responseText;
                }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkanswer.php?q=", true);
                // xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send();
                }            
        }
</script>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome Ben</h2>
<div onKeyPress="return verify(event)">
    <form id="verifyForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    Question 1 text:</br> <input type="text" id="mgolf">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="test"> 
    <p id="servRes">replace</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP

```
<?php

//create correct answer for test question

$answer = "Ben";
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

if($q == $answer) {
    echo "correct answer";
} else {
    echo "incorrect answer";
}
?>
```

Comment: "innterHTML" (sic)

Comment: oh god......fixing that unfortunately didn't fix the overall issue though

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, because you are calling .submit(); on form element, which in result refreshes a page and you don't see a result of XMLHttpRequest. Removing this line and fixing 'innterHTML' make your code working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Verify Identity</title>
    </head>
<script>
        function verify(e) {
            if((e && e.keyCode == 13) || e == 0) {
                // document.forms.verifyForm.submit();
                var golfer = document.getElementById("mgolf").value;
                // window.alert("You answered: " + golfer);
                //adding the ajax php call attempt 1 
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("servRes").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkanswer.php?q=", true);
                // xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send();
                }            
        }
</script>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome Ben</h2>
<div onKeyPress="return verify(event)">
    <form id="verifyForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    Question 1 text:</br> <input type="text" id="mgolf">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="test"> 
    <p id="servRes">replace</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! I have been stuck on this for almost a week and it means a lot you took the time to help me. This really helped.